# Messages 'lost' with Kafka topic with 2 partitions, and sent with key, while OK with 1 partition

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using Kafkapython running on python 3.8, and deployed a Kafka cluster docker-based from Confluent. Producers and Consumers also embedded in Docker containers

When my topic is made of one partition, there is no problem : all sent messages are pushed into topic (verify by my own counters = counters reported by Control Center)

But, when I configure 2 partitions for this topic, and traffic is loadbalanced with key, there are some messages "lost".

- My sent counter shows '1900 messages sent' (same as "single partition")
- While Control Center shows about 1800 messages in the topic (almost 50% in each partition)
- Confirmed at Consumer side, with 1800 messages consumed

There is not any Exception at producer side

As I'm quite new in Kafka, I'd appreciate some help about investigating this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the numbers not in ControlCenter but rather with a console-consumer to see if you can match the expected number of messages?

Comment: I did it. Unfortunately, at KafkaConsumer level, the number of messages (1800) is lower than expected (1900).

Comment: Can you show the code for the KafkaProducer you are applying?

Comment: In fact, I solved my issue. I was previously using kafka-python. So, I switched to confluent-kafka, and applied the standard producer-consumer example provided. It works fine !